# Proguard and Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, proguard

I modified my apk-file using Proguard and published it in Google Play. Now I have some errors like

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
> $$PACKAGENAME$$.SInit@45e44d88 with null:
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3282)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:135) at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2211)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException at $$PACKAGENAME$$.SInit.a(Unknown
> Source) at $$PACKAGENAME$$.SInit.onStartCommand(Unknown Source) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3267)
> ... 10 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

proguard-project.txt:

```
 -keep public class $$PACKAGENAME$$.ids._Bredi { public *; }
 -keep public class $$PACKAGENAME$$.libs.info { public *; }
 -keep public class com.android.vending.billing.util.* { public *; }
```

Comment: Post your ProGuard config.

Comment: i posted proguard-project.txt

Comment: Android has a LOT more requirements for ProGuard. Please look at this link: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Comment: I think you are right. This is the core of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html